# Servidor apache no se inicia al agregar una extencion en httpd.conf

Tags: codeigniter, apache, xampp, composer

Estoy empazando a usar **CodeIgniter** (CodeIgniter 4). Para crear un nuevo proyecto, en las instrucciones que he seguido indican utilizar **Composer**. Todo bien hasta que: en el archivo `httpd.conf` me indican des-comentar la extension `;extension=intl` eliminando el punto y coma(;). Lo he hecho, pero al reiniciar **Apache** (en **xampp**) se apaga (no arranca)! con el error:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

**¿ Qué debería hacer para que acepte la activacion de la extension ?**
**¿ Hay otro camino que no tenga que agregar la extension `intl` ?**

Vi en un muro donde a algunos les funcionó `extension=php_intl.dll` en lugar de `extension=intl`. Pero a mí nada de eso!

Comment: Esa extensión es de PHP, así que esa instrucción no debería estar en la configuración de Apache, sino en el php.ini. El error se debe a una configuración incorrecta de apache http (PD. tienes que bajar el .dll / .so de la extensión, aunque ese viene incluido en PHP > 7.2, creo)

Comment: Perdona! Me había equivocado! en lugar de httpd.conf quería decir php.ini. La verdad es que no tengo idea de lo que es el .dll. Pero voy a investigar un poco :(

Comment: Las extensiones son librerías. Las librerías vienen en archivos, dll para windows (php_intl.dll) y so para linux (php_intl.so)